# Show that $A$ is a closed $^*-$subalgebra of $l^\infty(T)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $A\subset l^\infty(T)$ be the subalgebra consisting of those functions $f:T\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that the function $t\rightarrow f(e^{it}), t\in \mathbb{R}$ has left and right limits at each point of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $A$ is a closed $^*-$subalgebra of $l^\infty(T)$.

I proved that  $A$ is a $^*-$subalgebra. To prove it is closed I took a sequence $f_n$ in $A$ such that it converges uniformly to $f$ in $T$. So let $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0^+} f_n(e^{it})=F_n$. Then $\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0^+} f(e^{it})=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0^+} (\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(e^{it}))=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0^+} f_n(e^{it}))=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_n$. But now how do we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_n$ exists? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For $f\in A$ and $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, you have $\lvert \lim_{t\to t_0^+} f(e^{it})\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{l^\infty(T)}$.

Comment: Ok, that means $F_n's$ are bounded. But boundedness does not gurantee convergence.

Comment: More than that. It implies that $(F_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Or else can I go with a convergent subsequence of $(F_n)$?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to prove that $A$ is closed. Along the lines you started on, note that for every fixed $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, the map

$$L_{t_0} \colon A \to \mathbb{C};\quad f \mapsto \lim_{t \to t_0^+} f(e^{it})$$

is a continuous linear form with $\lVert L_{t_0}\rVert = 1$. Continuous linear forms are uniformly continuous (even Lipschitz continuous), so they map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

In your situation, the sequence $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$, and hence the sequence $(F_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$. Note however, that the interchange of the limits

$$\lim_{t\to t_0^+} \biggl(\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(e^{it})\biggr) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl(\lim_{t\to t_0^+} f_n(e^{it})\biggr)$$

requires a justification.

Another way is to show that the complement of $A$ is open. If $f \in l^\infty(T)\setminus A$, then by definition, there is a $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the left- or right-hand limit of $f(e^{it})$ at $t_0$ doesn't exist. Without loss of generality, assume the right-hand limit doesn't exist. And without loss of generality, assume that the right hand limit of $\operatorname{Re} f(e^{it})$ doesn't exist. Then

$$\delta := \limsup_{t \to t_0^+} \operatorname{Re} f(e^{it}) - \liminf_{t\to t_0^+} \operatorname{Re} f(e^{it}) > 0.$$

Now look at the ball with radius $\delta/3$ and centre $f$ to see that $f \notin \overline{A}$.

Comment: Can I say that the interchange of limits is valid since $f_n$ converges uniformly?

Comment: If you can refer to a proof of that fact (earlier in the course/book, in some other course you took/book you read), then that's okay. If you don't have a reference to a proof, you should prove it. But the argument is indeed that the uniform convergence justifies the interchange.